# Create Wishlist and Notify user when completed - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS Programming. I have an app with REST API.
I want to add functionality where I have to create a wishlist of books and then notify the user when some adds that book.

Please help me out in implementing this.
As of now I have no idea how this should be done. It would be great if you give me any idea.

Comment: do you want an architectural design of the final solution? or did you already try something? please, share some code you wrote, as it seems you are looking for someone who should develop a whole app

Comment: No, I'm looking for someone who will guide me into correct path. Right now i don't know from where to start, what logic should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

you should develop

1. an **iOS app** with

   - a connectionManager that will manage communication between the client app and the server about which book exist (in order to list them and record user preferences)
   - a `Storyboard` that describes the User Experience (a login view, book list view with a "put in wish list" action that will use the connectionManager to talk with the BE)
2. a **BackEnd server application**

   - here there will be web services and everything will be recorded for each user
   - here you should develop the logic to send notification to each user